# How to get all the job ids when dispatching a chain?

Tags: laravel

How can I retrieve all the jobIds that are dispatched in a chain, for example:

```
ProcessPodcast::withChain([
    new OptimizePodcast,
    new ReleasePodcast
])->dispatch();
```

What are the ids of the `ProcessPodcast`, `OptimizePodcast` and `ReleasePodcast` jobs?

Comment: are you need job id inside handle method? I mean when job start to run

Comment: No, I need the ids before the job is invoked.